# Ambiguous : Prioritize overloading of f(A&) over f(A)

Tags: c++, sfinae, ambiguous

How to prioritize (tell compiler) to use "a function receive reference"  (#B) over "a function receive value" (#A)?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Heavy{/* ...... */}; //a complex class
Heavy generateHeavy(){
    return Heavy();
}
void f(Heavy x){   //#A I want LOW priority.
    std::cout<<"case 1: pass by value"<<std::endl;
}
void f(Heavy& x){  //#B I want HIGH priority.  (save CPU for big object)
    std::cout<<"case 2: pass by reference"<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    //vvvv Here is existing code base that I don't want to touch.
    f(generateHeavy());   //compiler call case 1 -> ok (I prefer reference, though)
    Heavy heavy;
    f(heavy); //should call case 2, but compiler fail (ambiguous) <= question
    return 0;
}
```

This issue come from my first attempt to extend SFINAE to a real-world case that prefer passing by reference, if possible.

Comment: You should replace the `Heavy` overload by a `Heavy&&` one.

Comment: @StoryTeller   Good point.   Thus,I have to call std::move() when using it (sometimes)?  Sorry, I forgot to mention, I don't want to touch the existing code base much.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can also call it with a copy `Heavy(existing_heavy)`. The whole point is to avoid creating the copy by default.

Comment: Use a const reference.

Comment: @Paul Rooney  sometimes, I can't.   I understand your point.  :(

Comment: @javaLover:  If you have f(T&&) and f(T&), then the second can *only* be called if you have an l-value, and the first can only be called if you have an r-value.  You can create an r-value out of an l-value with std::move - but you don't want to, you want to call the T& version.

Comment: @Martin Bonner  It is a new knowledge for me.  Thank.

Comment: What is the use of this? The first version of `f()` is call by value, which means `f()` does not alter the `Heavy` that is passed to it. In that case there should just be a single `f(const Heavy&)`. Unless the overload has radically different behavior, but then it should have another name entirely.

Comment: @user1320881   Yes, it overload radically different behavior (inside), but I want to hide it from caller (it is SFINAE manipulation).      `f()` in one of the overloads can call a non-const function of `Heavy` (I omited it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to literally do as you asked is

```
template <typename T = void>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, void>::value> f(Heavy x) { ... }

void f(Heavy& x) { ... }
```

The first is a function template, but only `T = void` is allowed. The second is not. All else being equal, non-templates are preferred over templates.

---

Now, in real code, you probably wouldn't do this. You'd look at which calls you wish to support, and find a more appropriate approach that fits those calls. @StoryTeller suggested `&&`:

```
void f(Heavy &&) { ... }
void f(Heavy &) { ... }
```

which means that when you've got an rvalue, such as your function result, the `Heavy &&` overload will be called. That's usually fine, but note that it's not exactly the same as what you asked for:

```
const Heavy c;
f(c);
```

What you asked for would make this call `f(Heavy)`. Instead, with the `Heavy &&` overload, there is no overload that accepts this.

An additional overload `void f(const Heavy &)` could cover this. There's not enough information in the question to tell if this is an appropriate approach for your use case, but that's something that you should be able to figure out yourself.

Comment: If I use `f(Heavy &&)` and `f(Heavy &)`, there will be no heavy copy, right?       If there is no copy for both cases, it would be even better that I wished.  XD  (Live code just in case : https://ideone.com/xzb8F0 )

Comment: @javaLover Both overloads there take references, so there's no copying involved in a call to either overload. But practically speaking, given `void f(Heavy); Heavy g();` and then `f(g())` didn't involve a copy either. It's not strictly speaking guaranteed, but it's allowed, and multiple compilers really do it, to construct `g`'s result directly in the memory reserved for `f`'s parameter.